# php3 and php Variable Difference

Tags: php

I am working on converting some ancient .php3 code. While running the ancient .php3 version on the ancient box everything works fine. When I click the rewrite button it enters the rewrite if block.

.php3

```
<?
if($rewrite) {
//here is therewrite code
}

<input class="smButton" type="submit" name="rewrite" value="Save Changes">
```

.php

```
<?php
if($rewrite) {
//here is therewrite code
}

<input class="smButton" type="submit" name="rewrite" value="Save Changes">
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing? Something in the .php3 version sets the rewrite variable but in the new version it isn't set unless I manually set it at the top of the .php file.

Hopefully this is enough code. I am just wondering what could cause such different behaviors between the 2 versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) is probably on for PHP 3 and off in your newer PHP version (as it should be)

Comment: There's the culprit! This did the trick. Just changing the value from Off to On. For quick future reference to anyone this value is located in the php.ini config file. Personally mine was located at /etc/php/php.ini.

Comment: You should review your code instead of activate this crappy old feature :-). It's a bit dangerous to keep this behavior (override variables by accident for example...)

Comment: @Maxime Lorant Always a good idea. I'll put it on my todo list now that the differences in versions are slowly being worked out.

Answer (score 5):

You have to replace the `$rewrite` by `$_POST['rewrite']`, because your new PHP version doesn't activate [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php), which translate every `$_POST['x']` and `$_GET['x']` (and more generally `$_REQUEST['x']`) to `$x`)

This leads to a [bunch of security holes](http://dan.doezema.com/2010/04/php-register-globals-overview/), if you have PHP code of low quality (which can be the case if you haven't maintain it since years).